# Erro ao tentar instalar pacote NToastNotify pelo Nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, nuget

Estou tentando instalar o pacote:

> NToastNotify versão 5.0.10

em meu sistema:

> Asp.Net Core 2.1

Mas estou recebendo as seguintes mensagens:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery. Install/reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.2.0 directly to project KonBase to resolve this issue. 
>    KonBase -> NToastNotify 5.0.10 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.2.0) 
>    KonBase -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem duas alternativas:

1. Instalar a versão do NToastNotify 5.0.8 compatível com o ASP.NET Core 2.1

Install-Package NToastNotify -Version 5.0.8

2. Atualizar sua aplicação para utilizar o ASP.NET Core 2.2

Exemplo de Migração:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio